# how to access Firebase from Google Cloud using Java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

here's my situation: I have my database in Firebase and my backend logic in Google Cloud, the code is in Java, apparently I can't even authenticate to Firebase because it requires the usage of the auth SDK available only for android (it's tied to Play Services).
What I need to do is, from Google Cloud AppEngine, get data from Firebase so I can manipulate it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) to access your database from a server.